# First Silverlight application causing problem. Developer Runtime error

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have installed Visual Studio 2010 and Silverlight 4 tools. Still, i am getting an error while running my Silverlight application :-

`Unable to Start Debugging. The Silverlight Developer Runtime is not installed. Please install a matching version`

Why is this happening? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you *uninstall* the current Silverlight runtime from the control panel (add/remove programs) and reinstall the Silverlight Tool to get the developer (debuggable) version of the Silverlight Runtime instead.

The tools do not replace an existing installed version of Silverlight, so must be removed manually first.